# I need to exclude a point to a route using HERE SDK routing

Tags: java, android, routes, here-api

exclueRoutingZones() needs a list of strings. Someone help me put it in a right way

```
    List<String> avoidAreas = new ArrayList<String>();
    avoidAreas.add("10.296972,123.894966");
    avoidAreas.add("10.297257,123.895867");
    routeOptions.excludeRoutingZones(avoidAreas);
```

Answer (score 0):

Routinge zone exclusion need a list of Zone IDs - NOT geo coordinates.

See:

> https://developer.here.com/documentation/android-premium/api_reference_java/com/here/android/mpa/routing/RouteOptions.html#excludeRoutingZones-java.util.List-

You probably want to look closer at:

> https://developer.here.com/documentation/android-premium/api_reference_java/com/here/android/mpa/routing/DynamicPenalty.html

That includes some other exclusion options, e.g.:

> https://developer.here.com/documentation/android-premium/api_reference_java/com/here/android/mpa/routing/DynamicPenalty.html#addBannedArea-com.here.android.mpa.common.GeoPolygon-

where you can specify a polygon or also

> https://developer.here.com/documentation/android-premium/api_reference_java/com/here/android/mpa/routing/DynamicPenalty.html#addRoadPenalty-com.here.android.mpa.common.RoadElement-com.here.android.mpa.routing.DrivingDirection-int-

when you know the segment ID you want to block.

Comment: I appreciate your response :). Can i ask if you have sample codes with Zone Id's? or on the polygon?